# jQuery Mobile Popup is Showing Through another Popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, popup

**Scenario:** MVC Razor .NET application using the jQuery Mobile version 1.4.5 framework. I have my first popup that comes up after selecting an item from a list. That popup only confirms the item selected from a list from the previous page, and then it shows two buttons: Continue and Go Back. The Continue button calls a second pop. 
**Problem:**  The problem occurs immediately as soon as the first popup comes up; the second popup can be seen through the first one, almost as if they were merged together. I obviously need to get rid of this. Any ideas of where to start?

Here's my code for the first popup:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="PopupConfirmAssignment" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
        <h1>Assignment Confirmation</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h3 class="ui-title">You have selected to take photos for assignment number <span id="assignmentNumber">_____</span> for a <span id="vehicleInfo">_____</span></h3>            
        <a href="#" class="btnWidth" data-theme="c" style="margin: 0;" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Go Back</a>
        <a href="#PopupTotalLoss" class="btnWidth" style="margin-top: 0;" data-theme="b" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-inline="true">Continue > ></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the code for the second popup:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="PopupTotalLoss" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
        <h1>Potential Loss</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" style="text-align: center;">
        <h3 class="ui-title">Is this vehicle potentially a total loss?</h3>
        <input type="submit" onclick="setTotalLoss(1);" name="cmdTotalLossYes" value="Yes" data-role="button" data-inline="true" />
        <input type="submit" onclick="setTotalLoss(0);" name="cmdTotalLossNo" value="No&nbsp;" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQM does not allow chaining of popups directly. So you will need to close the first popup before showing the second one. As far as seeing both popups, how exactly are you launching the first popup?

Answer (score 0):

They will not merged together
First you have to close the first popup, then after have to open next popup.
    $("#PopupConfirmAssignment").popup("close");
    setTimeout(function() {
            $("#PopupTotalLoss").popup("open");
    }, 1000);